# Subsecond image cache / proxy

Tags: performance, http, caching, varnish

We are creating a preview of screen via browser polling an image 3 times per second. As the image is expensive to generate and there may be multiple people viewing it - we are looking at deploying varnish as a cache.

As RFCs do not allow for cache headers we are trying to configure varnish to override the cache headers and store the image in memory for 1/2 a second to server any subsequent requests.

Varnish is using an in memory cache - I am not sure if varnish is designed / tuned to cache for such a short period of time. Initial tests have resulted in all requests being cache misses.

Comment: So _what_ did you try already? Half a second will not work without alot of dirty hacks as the cache precision is in seconds. An easier solution might be to save the generated image in a pure key value store or on disk. That way you can control the cache time in milliseconds without problems.

Comment: We tried varnish - but web standards do not support the notion of sub second caching - for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now have a working solution based on Nginx and Redis (connecting using a Lua connector) - the performance is very impressive so far.